# How to maintain the color of a component when changing the style

Tags: delphi, themes

In a Delphi application I use `TLabeledEdit` to show a font size value in the edit field, whereas the associated `EditLabel` shows the other font properties, like color, boldness, etc.

The font can be selected after double-clicking on the edit field, which invokes a `TFontDialog` component. After the dialog is closed, the selected font is assigned to the `EditLabel`.

Everything works OK as long as I use the `"Windows"` style. But, switching to any other style, the color of the `EditLabel` is set to black, whatever I try with the settings of `ParentFont`, `ParentColor`, `StyleElements`, etc.

The easy solution is to stick with the default `"Windows"` style, but hopefully you can help me with some hints to get it working correctly.

Comment: This is about VCL styles, isn't it?

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: The idea with styles is that the whole application adhers to a give design. Therefore changing the appearance of various elements is not made very easy. The label of a `TLabeledEdit` is such an element (or maybe just overlooked). You could work around this by using separate `TLabel` and `TEdit`. Then you could untick `StyleElements.seFont` of the label and set the font family and color to what you want, both at design time and run time.

Comment: It is VCL indeed, and I am using version 10.4 Enterprise.

Comment: Tom, thank you for your hint. This might indeed be overlooked by Embarcadero. I will drop the use of LabeledEdits for the purpose of visualising fonts. Shouldn't it be regarded as a bug?

Comment: Yes, I would agree it is a bug. As all other UI text elements have the `StyleElements` property, there's no reason why the `EditLabel` doesn't have it. Priority is not high, though, as it can be replaced with separate `Label`s and `Edit`s. Let me know when you have filed a bug report, and I will votr for it. (To address people here at SO use @username which will be seen as a notification. Not needed to address question poster or an answerer under their answer.)